# Powerbuilder cannot Encode/decode URL's parameters

Tags: json, powerbuilder

I use the powerbuilder ole object to encode/decode the string like JSON, but when I use the ole object, I don't know how put my data to encoding it

Here is my testing data:
my testing data is like that [{"ref":"T213445677","pickdtime":"2018-02-02 09:00:00","compname":"Wing Kei Shoes Company"}]

Here is my coding

```
OleObject wsh
Integer  li_rc
string ls_temp

wsh = CREATE OleObject
li_rc = wsh.ConnectToNewObject( "MSScriptControl.ScriptControl" )
wsh.language = "javascript"

ls_temp = wsh.Eval("escape('[{"ref":"T213445677","pickdtime":"2018-02-02 
09:00:00","compname":"Wing Kei Shoes Company"}]')")

MessageBox( "ESCAPE" , ls_temp)

ls_temp = wsh.Eval("unescape('" + ls_temp + "')")

MessageBox( "UNESCAPE" , ls_temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at this article regarding a JSON parser written in Visual Basic for Applications (VBA).  It can be found here: http://ashuvba.blogspot.com/2014/09/json-parser-in-vba-browsing-through-net.html

The current version of PowerBuilder (2017 R2) has native JSON parsing built into the datawindow.

Answer (score 0):

I have an example app that shows how to post messages to Twitter from PowerBuilder. It includes functions for encoding. The zip file includes PB 8 and PB 10 versions.